# Django authenticate function returning None when passed existing username and password

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am having trouble getting the Django `authenticate` function to work the way I expect. When I create a new user and try to authenticate in the manner [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in), the `authenticate()` function returns `None`. I have seen **many** posts about "`authenticate` not working", but none of the solutions work for me. Here is a demonstration:

```
In [34]: user = User.objects.create(username='fakeuser', email='fake@fakemail.com', password='abc')

In [35]: user
Out[35]: <User: fakeuser>

In [39]: auth_user = authenticate(username='fakeuser', password='abc')

In [40]: print(auth_user)
None
```

It is my understanding that `authenticate()` in this case should return an object that I can then pass to the `login()` function to log the user in, but I get `None` instead. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating the user wrong. Django will always hash the password passed to authenticate, but you're creating the user with a plain text password.

Use `create_user` instead.

Comment: I knew about the password hashing, but obviously didn't fully understand what was going on. I knew not to pass `user.password` to `authenticate()`, but didn't realize how things worked with password creation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Django's password hashing is the problem, as Daniel Rosemann has stated in his answer. You can also solve this in two steps:

```
>>> user = User.objects.create(username='fakeuser', email='fake@fakemail.com', password='whatever')
>>> user.set_password('abc')  # takes plain text and stores the hash

>>> user.check_password('abc')
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the added info!